# Left join two tables, and then append only new rows to table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to take all records from tblForecast and the matching records from tblOpenJobs and append them to tblWorkingTable, but only if the [Job #] does not yet exist in tblWorkingTable.

The first part (through the first Left Join) works fine, but the second left join and Where statement fail with a Syntax error:

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'A.[Job #]= B.[Job #] LEFT JOIN tblWorkingTable AS C ON A.[Job #] = C.[Job#'.

I'm pretty new to SQL, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I could probably get it to work with two separate queries, but it would be really ideal to get it all to work in one.

```
INSERT INTO tblWorkingTable ( [Rec'd], ForecastMonth, [Ship Week], [Commit Date], [Job #], Customer, [Part #], Released, [Forecast Qty], [Actual Qty], Shipped, [Sales Price], [Sales Value], Invoice, Comments )
SELECT B.[Rec'd], A.ForecastMonth, A.[Ship Week], A.[Commit Date], A.[Job #], A.Customer, A.[Part #], B.Released, A.Qty AS [Forecast Qty], B.Qty AS [Actual Qty], B.Shipped, A.[Sales Price], A.[Sales Value], A.Invoice, A.Comments
FROM tblForecast AS A 
LEFT JOIN tblOpenJobs AS B ON A.[Job #] = B.[Job #]
LEFT JOIN tblWorkingTable AS C ON A.[Job #] = C.[Job #]
Where ((C.[Job #]) is Null);
```

And yes, I know, there shouldn't be special characters in those field names. I need to assign those a different name during the data import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access requires parentheses around joins.  Try this:

```
INSERT INTO tblWorkingTable ( [Rec'd], ForecastMonth, [Ship Week], [Commit Date], [Job #], Customer, [Part #], Released, [Forecast Qty], [Actual Qty], Shipped, [Sales Price], [Sales Value], Invoice, Comments )
    SELECT B.[Rec'd], A.ForecastMonth, A.[Ship Week], A.[Commit Date], A.[Job #], A.Customer, A.[Part #], B.Released, A.Qty AS [Forecast Qty],
           B.Qty AS [Actual Qty], B.Shipped, A.[Sales Price], A.[Sales Value], A.Invoice, A.Comments
    FROM (tblForecast AS A LEFT JOIN
          tblOpenJobs AS B
          ON A.[Job #] = B.[Job #] 
         ) LEFT JOIN
         tblWorkingTable AS C
         ON A.[Job #] = C.[Job #]
    WHERE C.[Job #] is Null;
```